# php-fpm consum memeory and make server unable to accessed?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, ubuntu

I have launch an ec2 server on AWS (os:ubuntu , type:t2.micro) used for laravel project as backend for my application the server is working fine , but in next day when I need to ssh the server It refuse and get error (connection time out) , after search for reason of problem I have found that it may be because of consume cpu and memory , so I have confused:

1) Is php-fpm consume more than 1G from memory (If that true how my server work fine at first In spite of using 1G for server)?

2) Is php-fpm still consume memory even if no requests enter it as I have change my domain for backend to another server (server with the problem no more serve my app) ?

3) what I have to do for solving the problem of the server to be able ssh on it ?

***hint : this is image for cloudwatch monitoring
[image]

Comment: I do no think it can be just happen on very next day if there is not much data and files. Check the inbound rules at your aws account and check the actual issue from monitoring where analytics shown as graphical view date wise.

Comment: thanks for reply , I have already check  inbound rules and it fine (there is no change) , about graphical monitoring I have add it to my question it show there is no consuming for cpus